# Access SQL server via lotus notes designer

Tags: sql-server, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

It's been a long time already I've been googling to find instructions on how to **connect SQL server database via Lotus notes designer and vice versa**. I'm not talking here about XPages. I'm just so new to Lotus Notes Designer and lotus script. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Although there is a design element called "Data Connection Resource" to connect a NSF file to a SQL database it is not very practical to use it. You can read everything about it in the very good domino- designer- help. Just check [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ACCESSING_DATA_IN_ENTERPRISE_APPLICATIONS_STEPS.html) to get a starting point.

But as you are new to the matter I am quite sure, that you don't really NEED such a connection. Only a very little percentage of the applications I develop really need to access relational data from other datasources...

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll be needing to access relational database, which is SQL as I'm being tasked to create application with lotus notes designer that would get/retrieve data from sql server. Anyways, I'll be continuing with my studies on interaction between the two.